# Where is commit message syntax hilighting in IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting, intellij-14

[image: commit dialog]The syntax highlighting style I'm using has a light grey font on a white background for the commit message prompt. Where in the syntax highlighting configuration can I tweak the colors used for this?

[image: picture of default text dialog]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings | Editor | Colors & Fonts | General | Default text

Note that IntelliJ IDEA has custom logic that always uses the background color from the default scheme (ignoring your customizations) in UI elements such as panels and dialog text fields if the UI theme is default (not Darcula) and the editor is configured to use a dark background color. You may want to change the color scheme to Darcula in Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance | Theme.

Comment: unless I'e got something severely broken (how?), changing the background color of Default text doesn't change the background color of this prompt.

Comment: Just tried this, works for me. http://screencast.com/t/bBEj3RN6l http://screencast.com/t/r5wkoBJwc

Comment: I just uploaded a screenshot of the default text configuration

Comment: well that's interesting, it ignores the background but picks up the foreground... switching to windows theme fixed the problem, this is supposed to be a non-darcula varient, I don't  actually want my entire IDE to be dark